# What is the default random number generator seed in boost?

Tags: c++, boost, random

If one doesn't specify a seed for the boost RNG, it uses a default one. The documentation mentions [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_random/tutorial.html) , but I can't find the actual value, which would be nice to know for testing whether the setting of the seed works as expected. Where can I find it? Is it platform dependent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default seed for Mersenne Twister is `5489u`.

Find the other ones [here](https://github.com/boostorg/random/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=default_seed).

```
lagged_fibonacci       | 331u      |
subtract_with_carry    | 19780503u |
inversive_congruential | 1         |
linear_feedback_shift  | 341       | 
linear_congruential    | 1         |
mersenne_twister       | 5489u     |
```

Comment: great, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Nice one with the search link :)